# Ordering groups individual after renaming

Tags: javascript, tabulator

My product table is sorted with `initialSort` by the product release month ascending. I also grouped my products by a codename which is determinate by the ajax json response url and renamed them to readable names with a `groupBy` function. Now I want to sort my groups individual without loosing the month sorting in my groups. How is that possible?

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#tableid", {
  ajaxURL: url,
  layout: "fitColumns",
  groupBy: "codename",
  groupBy:function(data){
    if (data.codename == "X123") {
      return "Productname for X123";
    }
    if (data.codename == "X124") {
      return "Productname for X124";
    }
    …
    …
  },
  initialSort:[
      {column:"month", dir:"asc"}
  ],  
  columns: [
    { title: "Product", field: "codename"},
    { title: "Month", field: "month"},
    …
    …
    …
  ]
});
```

Comment: Provide the part of code where you are doing the sorting. This code part is not enough to reproduce and answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean by "sort my groups individual", but is this what you're looking for ?

https://jsfiddle.net/r3f7pysw/

```
initialSort:[
      {column:"month", dir:"asc"},
      {column:"codename", dir:"asc"}
  ],
```

NOTE(1) : I dont think you *want* to return that string for your grouping, when it seems like its just the header Display string, and you're still going to be sorting on "codename" (becoz the string is the same with a change at the end, which really takes a "little" long to compare each time). But maybe you do...

NOTE(2) : Adding the seconds initialSort is like Ctrl-Click on the sorting to sort by multiple criteria. So if you single click on say, Month, remember that destroys the currentSort array and sets it just to Month.

Comment: Thanks for your answer/feedback! Very helpful. Is there any way to "lock" the sorting from 1 column? Or is there a way to trigger the CTRL-Click for a column?
If I click twice, my multiple sorting is gone :(

Comment: See here: https://jsfiddle.net/k0ewLh7y/ 
I want to lock the positions of the renamed Group Header and sort only the values in the cells.

Comment: OK, its *ugly*, but it seems the only thing I could think of doing was to re-sort after making sure that one column was the last in the list of sorting columns. See(https://jsfiddle.net/wqnxrv0u/) and the use of the dataSorted callback

Comment: Hm, good Idea – I will check if I can go on with this. The problem is still that I want an individual group sorting, not asc or desc. I want to say If codename = X123 go on 1, if codename = X124 go on 3 and so one, and its feels ab bit laggy with more data. I think there is no "clean" Option to do this.

Comment: You can add another column and create that data on the client side with a Mutator and group by this new column. Or you can do it on the data creating side and have it already in the data feed.